# iframe contents cant appear in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, iframe

Below is my code:

```
<div style="border: solid 1px #000000; margin: 5px;">
  <iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com" width="100%" height="300px" scrolling="yes"><p>Your browser does not support iframe.</p></iframe>     
</div>
```

Contents of iframe works well in chrome but not in firefox. I've disabled add-ons but my iframe is still empty. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Works fine for me on FF 23 ? http://jsfiddle.net/ZWMbG/

Comment: For me too. Try to check adblock, noscript, your antivirus off (then restart browser. Also you can check what happens on web-console while you open the page.

Comment: I am using Firefox 23.0.1 but its not working..just showing white empty box..

Answer (score 23):

If you are trying to add this Iframe on a SSL-encrypted website (https://), it won't work any more since Firefox 23 because Mozilla has decided to blocked all unencrypted content on encrypted websites (for example http-iframes on https-websites). 
You can change this behaviour in your own Firefox installation by typing `about:config` in the address bar and setting `security.mixed_content.block_active_content` to `false`.
But that won't help you for all other FF23-visitors on your website.

Comment: Can't we do this by writing some piece javascript code?

Comment: Is the chromium-browser also has the same situation?

Comment: Can we use HTTPS iframes on HTTPS websites?

Comment: dose not work https iframe

Comment: This solution looked promising but I tried it for FireFox in 2024 and it didn't work in incognito (private) window

Answer (score 16):

As of 05/2018, the iframe lead is denied by browser due to X-Frame-Options header set to 'sameorigin'.

Tested the page with Firefox and getting blank iframe.
Here is what console says:

```
Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://www.w3schools.com/ does not permit cross-origin framing.
```

Why that?I'll give Chrome console a chance, here's what it says:

```
Refused to display 'https://www.w3schools.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.
```

Basically, X-Frame-Options header (do not confuse that with CORS), is set to 'sameorigin', that means that the browser is allowed to display the iframe content only if embedded in same domain and same protocol (https://www.w3schools.com/ is not sameorigin of http://www.w3schools.com/).

Here are some docs aboiut x-frame-options:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

Comment: Are you trying to iframe embed an external domain page into local page / what other kind of situation are you into?@Alex

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: Can you have control over the headers of the page you trying to embed into the iframe?@Alex

Comment: No, but I found a workaround.  Do a window.open, and use a script to resize/move/focus the opened window to correspond to the parent window.  Not an ideal solution, but it works for the end user.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if its related but when I try to request w3schools by c# it responses 503 forbidden error. So they may use something to prevent showing up on iframes, etc. Facebook has similiar restrictions, you cannot display their likebox iframe unless you log in.

Comment: It was working yesterday in FF when I did it for the first time but when I hit my URL,it starts showing nothing in my all iframes. Not for w3schools only..

Comment: If there would be a 503 error, why does Firefox not show it then? This would be a bug in the browser. I noticed that loading the https site of google.com results in an empty frame. It seems that google detects the iframe and sends an empty page. While I can load a https site of my bank without problems!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. For me the cause was a trailing slash at the end of the url.

Doesn't work:

```
<iframe src="http://example.com/some/sub/folder/"></iframe>
```

Works:

```
<iframe src="http://example.com/some/sub/folder"></iframe>
```

Comment: Not in my case...

Answer (score 1):

Why no one has mentioned CORS yet?

FROM [**mdn**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

> Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) is a mechanism that uses
>   additional HTTP headers to let a user agent gain permission to access
>   selected resources from a server on a different origin (domain) than
>   the site currently in use. A user agent makes a cross-origin HTTP
>   request when it requests a resource from a different domain, protocol,
>   or port than the one from which the current document originated.
>
> An example of a cross-origin request: A HTML page served from
>   http://domain-a.com makes an  src request for
>   http://domain-b.com/image.jpg. Many pages on the web today load
>   resources like CSS stylesheets, images, and scripts from separate
>   domains, such as content delivery networks (CDNs).
>
> For security reasons, browsers restrict cross-origin HTTP requests
>   initiated from within scripts. For example, XMLHttpRequest and the
>   Fetch API follow the same-origin policy. This means that a web
>   application using those APIs can only request HTTP resources from the
>   same domain the application was loaded from unless CORS headers are
>   used.

This means that the websites you are trying to enter from the iframe are set to deny requests from your site or others (if not all).

Comment: For example. With the url given by your html I get the following on Mozilla Developer Edition "Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://www.w3schools.com/ does not permit cross-origin framing."

Comment: Try this url http://example.com/. If this one loads then your problem is due to CORS (if there is no add-on messing with your browser).

Comment: So how do I get around this, if I definitely need to put a certain site in an iframe?

Comment: If the website you are trying to access through an iframe is not owned by you then you should ask the owner to add your domain to their CORS whitelist.

Comment: Follow this https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/08/bypass-cors-errors-testing-apis-locally/

Comment: Their suggestion didn't work on Firefox, and there's no suggestion for IE; however, I still upvoted your answer since you've put in much effort.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the problem using **Django** you need to set the following option in your settings:

```
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = "SAMEORIGIN"
```

As is documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/clickjacking/#how-to-use-it). The default value is set to `DENY` and therefore blocking all attempts.

Answer (score -2):

You need to have source file of iframe on localhost.

Firefox and Chrome doesn't display this iframe:

```
<iframe src="https://www.yourdomain.com/form.html"></iframe>
```

Works:

```
<iframe src="/form.html"></iframe>
```