# Firefox - Embedded video not loading?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, iframe

I have 2 embedded video from youtube which work fine and then I have 3 embedded videos from vrideo.com that doesn't work in my wordpress website. Everything(youtube and vrideo) works great on Chrome, Safari, Opera and yes even IE :)

Unfortunately it does not work on Firefox, it seems like the video is not being loaded. The screen just stays empty. The weird thing is when I change the source code of the iframe in my browser with the embedded link that I copy from vrideo.com it does work. When I compare the iframe code that I copy with the one that's already in it, it's exactly the same.

The source code (doesn't work):

```
<iframe src="http://www.vrideo.com/embed/RKSFWQm" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="1" frameborder="0" height="350" width="560"></iframe>
```

The embedded link that I copy from vrideo.com (works):

```
<iframe src="http://www.vrideo.com/embed/RKSFWQm" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="1" frameborder="0" height="350" width="560"></iframe>
```

So weird, they're exactly the same but it doesn't work.

I get this nasty errors in my console 3 times(3videos):

```
NS_ERROR_FAILURE: 
TypeError: VRIDEO.Player is not a constructor
```

It's about this line of code in JS

```
var player = new VRIDEO.Player("mainVideo", playerProperties);
```

Anyone can help me out or has experienced anything similar?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iframe contents cant appear in Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18373592/iframe-contents-cant-appear-in-firefox)

Comment: I don't think this applies to me since I don't have any other iframe in my iframe, I do have multiple iframes on my page (2 from youtube(works fine) and 3 from vrideo)

Comment: Updated OP with console errors

Comment: You can try to add the url of the video from both. not the url code provided by youtube.

Comment: The iframes from youtube work great. The problem are the 3 videos from vrideo.com.

Comment: Try to copy and paste the video url instead of using iframe for the 3 videos left.

Comment: I discovered something funny, the video works whatever I add in the iframe, for example I do "edit as html on the iframe" and add "foo="foo"" the video works