# Iframe content not loading in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have iframe in my pop up. the content of iframe's set by

```
$('.document-acceptance-container .documentIframe')
  .contents()
  .find('body')
  .html(this.model.get('data').DocumentRecord.DocumentBodyPath);
```

It work's fine in Chrome and content of iframe is loaded, but in firefox iframe is empty. I set

`security.mixed_content.block_active_content` to `false`  and disabled addblock.

But it didn't help me.If I set a breakpoint on this line in debug mode in firefox - content was loaded. 
Have you any idea?
P.S: `DocumentRecord.DocumentBodyPath` is html code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iframe contents cant appear in Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18373592/iframe-contents-cant-appear-in-firefox)

Comment: Are you reading the iframe before the content is loaded?

Comment: I set security.mixed_content.block_active_content to false and disabled addblock, but problem is the same

Comment: Have you [read this](https://blog.mozilla.org/tanvi/2013/04/10/mixed-content-blocking-enabled-in-firefox-23/)

Comment: I solve this!) The answer is set set load function on iframe!

Comment: @Евгений could you please provide an example of the solution?