# Firefox print blank page

Tags: javascript, firefox

In my angular 7 project I need to print some PDF and if possible I don't want to use a third part library so I found this code online:

```
           const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
           iframe.style.display = 'none';
           iframe.src = blobUrl;
           document.body.appendChild(iframe);
           iframe.contentWindow.print()
```

It works perfect in chrome and opera but in firefox it prints a blank page.
I try also with a setTimout when I print but I have an error in this case:

> offsetParent is not set -- cannot scroll
>
> ERROR DOMException: "Permission denied to access property "print" on cross-origin object"

So is there a solution for firefox?

p.s. without touching the browser preferences.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18373592/iframe-contents-cant-appear-in-firefox could this maybe help?

Comment: @Kevin.a So what is in my case the iframe.src, if I don't but blobUrl I don't see any pdf

Comment: Did you finally found a solution ? I get the same problem...

Answer (score 3):

OK I found a solution:

```
   const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
   iframe.style.display = 'none';
   iframe.src = blobUrl;
   document.body.appendChild(iframe);    
   iframe.onload = () => {
       setTimeout(() => {
          iframe.focus();
          iframe.contentWindow.print();
       });
    };
```